# Accessing the ATTR field troubleshooting in Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

I am working on Tableau server but I believe the problem I am facing does not correspond to tableau server specifically.
I am using two data sources `ds1` and `ds2` which are joined using the dimension `Id` . `ds1` has a field `city` and `ds2` has a field `district`. There is only 1 city corresponding to each `Id` but there can be multiple district corresponding to an `Id` .
I have created a calculated field `Points` in `ds2` which is described in the code segment.

I have researched from different sites and blogs (including tableau support). I came to a close possible reason behind this and I might be wrong . The `ATTR` function which works on row level and identify if a row is unique then it outputs the `dimension` otherwise it outputs `'*'` . I think when I joined those two tables the `district` dimension in `ds2` might have the `'*'` instead of actual `district` values, so it might not be able to compare the conditions in if statements of `Point` .

```
//Point//

IF [city] == "Delhi"
AND [district] == "Dist1"
AND [district] == "Dist2"
THEN "100 Section"

ELSEIF [city] == "Mumbai"
AND [district] == "Dist11"
AND [district] == "Dist12"
THEN "200 Section"

ELSE "Other Section"
END
```

When I insert data which satisfy the conditions in calculated field, it is going in `Other` section of the `Point` .I want it to go in desired section.
For instance
`Id = 19` 
`city = Delhi`
`district = Dist1`
`district = Dist2`
`district = Dist3`

It should go in `100 Section` but it is going in `Other Section` . What modifications should I do or add to make the `Point` work properly ?

Comment: You're checking values at the row level, and `[district]` can never be equal to 'Dist1' and 'Dist2' at the same time -- it can be one or the other. You might benefit from a pivot or string aggregation in an earlier step.

Comment: Or you could use "OR" instead of "AND".

Comment: @Andy I am restricted to use pivot in my server. Can you explain a little more about how i can use string aggregation in this case? Or any other work around ?

Comment: @wavery I think using 'OR' will nullify the logic I am using in calculated field. Don't you think ?

Comment: @Prakhar The OR would just be in place of the 2nd AND because logically it can only be in one district I would think.

Comment: @wavery one city can have many districts. So if city is `Delhi` and it has two districts namely `Dist1` and `Dist2` then the measure should go to the `100 Section` . I hope this clears my requirement.

Comment: I would think OR would still work but if not I think you could use a CASE statement. I can post the code if you like.

Comment: @wavery Suppose there is no record where `Delhi` has `Dist2` then the measure should not go to `100 Section` . Similarly If there is no record where `Delhi` has `Dist1` then it should not go to `100 Section` either. So AND is a perfect logical operator here.